# Regex - match set of words literally with special characters at the front and back of each word

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex matcher.

```
const regex = /\b(?:days|weeks|months)\b/gi
```

If I pass a string like

`There are 5 $days/$ and ten %weeks/% and 7 $months/$`

I want to return an array with all the matches for each word like

```
['months', 'days', 'weeks'] 

or

['$months/$', '$days/$', '%weeks/%']
```

However, this string should not return `days` since there is no delimiter `$` or `/$` or `%` or `/%`

```
There are 5 days and ten %weeks/% and 7 $months/$

would return


['months', 'weeks'] 

or

['$months/$', '%weeks/%']
```

Here is what I have tried without success (just for days for now)

```
/\b(?:\$days|weeks|months)\b/gi
/\b(?:\$days\/\$|weeks|months)\b/gi
```

What is the correct pattern to match these 3 specific words with these particular delimiters that I append to the end of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial regex can be fixed like this:

```
/(?<=([$%]))(?:days|weeks|months)(?=\/\1)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnaGIT/1). A capturing group version:

```
/(?:\/?\$|\/?%)(days|weeks|months)\b/g
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnaGIT/2). The point is that you used a word boundary before the dollar symbol before `days` and it made the pattern only match `$days` right after a letter, digit or underscore. By using a custom boundary, the lookbehind or a group, this is easily fixed.

If you need to find the values only if there is a special char at the front and the same char after `/` at the end, you may use

```
/(?<=([$%]))(?:days|weeks|months)(?=\/\1)/g
/([$%])(days|weeks|months)\/\1/g
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnaGIT/3) and [this one](https://regex101.com/r/ZnaGIT/4).

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const strings = ['There are 5 $days/$ and ten %weeks/% and 7 $months/$', 'There are 5 days and ten %weeks/% and 7 $months/$'];
for (const x of strings) {
  // Getting clean results with the lookaround-based pattern:
  console.log(x.match(/(?<=([$%]))(?:days|weeks|months)(?=\/\1)/g, x));
  // Getting whole matches and clean results:
  const results = [...x.matchAll(/([$%])(days|weeks|months)\/\1/g)];
  console.log(Array.from(results, m => [m[0], m[2]]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a match method and RegExp object.

```js
let sentense = 'There are 5 $days/$ and ten %weeks/% and 7 $months/$';
let regex = new RegExp('(month)|(week)|(days)','gmi');
 let filter = sentense.match(regex);
 console.log(filter)    //["days", "week", "month"]
```